# How to add basic style to search pattern in JavaScript using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I can search a text in a paragraph using regular expression in JavaScript. What I want is, instead of displaying the searched pattern I want to apply basic styling to the search text, such as yellow background (or bold text)!

eg. My name is Mr. John
pattern: /M(r|s|rs).?/
Output: My name is **Mr.** John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this using a word boundary `\b` and end with a dot. Replace with capturing group 1 `$1`:

[`\b(M(?:r|s|rs)\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/gNIgv0/1)

```js
var str = "My name is Mr. John Mr Test Mrtest aMr";
str = str.replace(/\b(M(?:r|s|rs)\.)/g, "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>$1</span>");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Worked! I am getting the result without using word boundary.

pat = "/([a-z.0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-z]{2,4})/g;
styl.innerHTML = (ori.innerHTML.replace(pat, "<b>$1</b>" ));
styl.innerHTML = (ori.innerHTML.replace(pat, "<b>$1</b>" ))

Comment: Btw, can I use classList.add to add the style?

Comment: If you are referring to [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), I see examples of adding a class to the element.

Comment: Yes, but how can I add class using regex in JavaScript?

Comment: You could add the classname in the replacement: `    str = str.replace(/\b(M(?:r|s|rs)\.?)\b/g, "<span class='myClass'>$1</span>");
` and then use css to style it.

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my problem. I love Stackoverflow. You guys are very helpful.

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML` as it will destroy all events in the target element. Use e.g. mark.js instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mark.js, an node library that serves the purpose and provides multiple functionalities.

Have a look at the example code here:

HTML:

```
<h2><a href="https://markjs.io/" target="_blank">mark.js</a> example with custom regular expressions</h2>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Search</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="search row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <span>Type in a regular expression:</span>
        <input type="text" name="regex" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="/Lor[^]?m/gmi">
        <button type="button" name="mark" class="btn btn-primary">Mark</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <span>Search options:</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="debug"> debug
        <br>
        <span>There are a lot more <a target="_blank" href="https://markjs.io/configurator.html">options</a>!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body context">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit āmet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, nò sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie çonsequat, vel illum dolore
      eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit prāesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    </p>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>
      <small>Demo by <a href="https://github.com/julmot" target="_blank">Julian Motz</a></small>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 15px;
}

div.search span,
div.search input[name="regex"] {
  display: block;
}

div.search input[name="regex"],
button {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

div.panel {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

div.panel .panel-body p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

mark {
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here the 'mark' tag is where you add your required styling.

JS:

```
$(function() {

  var mark = function() {

    // Read input
    var inputstring = $("input[name='regex']").val();
    if (inputstring.trim() === "") {
      return;
    }

    // Create regex
    var flags = inputstring.replace(/.*\/([gimy]*)$/, '$1');
    var pattern = inputstring.replace(new RegExp('^/(.*?)/' + flags + '$'), '$1');
    var regex = new RegExp(pattern, flags);

    // Determine selected options
    var options = {};
    $("input[name='opt[]']").each(function() {
      options[$(this).val()] = $(this).is(":checked");
    });

    // Mark the regex inside the context
    $(".context").unmark({
      done: function() {
        $(".context").markRegExp(regex, options);
      }
    });
  };


  // Trigger mark action on button click
  $("button[name='mark']").on("click", mark);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/idhruvs/cyzctc8b/2/

Comment: That may be useful but I'm strictly preferring vanilla JS for this purpose.

Comment: Using the .replace function works in that case.

http://jsfiddle.net/idhruvs/4sGLL/272/

Comment: @LearnerAKS mark.js is also available as vanilla version